# Prepared statements mysqli php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some code that works (mysqli), but I need to make it secure from SQL injection:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO scratch_entry (email, fname, lname, phone, promo) VALUES ('$email', '$fname', '$lname', '$phone', $promo);";
```

I attempted to use a prepared statement, but I keep getting the error **Fatal error**: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

This is what I am attempting to use and is giving me the error:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO scratch_entry (email, fname, lname, phone, promo) VALUES(:email, :fname, :lname, :phone, :promo");
$stmt->bind_param(":email", $email);
$stmt->bind_param(":fname", $fname);
$stmt->bind_param(":lname", $lname);
$stmt->bind_param(":phone", $phone);
$stmt->bind_param(":promo", $promo);
$stmt->execute();
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong with this prepared statement? If you need more info let me know. Thanks!

Comment: That looks like PDO, should be ? instead of :email, then bind_param("sssss",$email,$fname,$lname,$phone,$promo);

Comment: The prepare query is missing a closing `)` at the end.